# Fundamental groupoid of a foliation is not Hausdorff

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, foliations, lie-groupoids

Let $F$ be a foliation of a smooth manifold $M$. The fundamental groupoid $\Pi(F)$ of $F$ is the set

$\Pi(F)=\frac{\{\alpha:[0,1]\to M\text{ path cointained in a leaf}\}}{\text{homotopy with fixed end points }}$.

I can't see why the fundamental groupoid of the foliation of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ by horizontal planes is not Hausdorff. Any help would be welcomed :)

Comment: What does a foliation being Hausdorff have to do with the fundamental group?

Comment: Which topology is being considered on the fundamental groupoid? This groupoid is basically $\mathbb{Z}$, the fundamental group of the leaf passing through the origin, since the contribution from every other leaf is just the identity class.